# startActivityForResult returning null when back navigation to activity sending result returns

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 3 activities that start in a sequence.With the first activity needing a result from the last activity.

I have it so that if Activity B is started for result (By activity A) then Activity B starts activity C for result. Then once the result is captured at activity C it is finished which calls Activity B's onActivityResult which sets the result and finishes and Activity A's onActivityResult gets the final result.

Activity A starts Activity B for a result which Activity C contains thus the sequence is like so

A->B->C (get result) C->B->A (result retrieved)

This works just fine if everything happens in sequence. However, If I navigate to activity C then press the toolbars back arrow and which leads me to activity B then navigate back to activity C and select the result. The result returned to activity A is null.

A->B->C->B->C(get result)  C->B->A (result == null)

**Activity A**

```
public class AlertCreationActivity extends AppCombatActivity {

   // OnCreate methods left out to shorten code

    @OnClick(R.id.locationButton)
    public void locationButtonClicked() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, StateActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(StateActivity.IS_STARTED_FOR_RESULT, StateActivity.STARTED_FOR_RESULT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ALERT_CREATION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == ALERT_CREATION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String title = data.getStringExtra(ALERT_CREATION_REQUEST_DATA);
            if ( ! title.isEmpty()) {
                mLocationButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mLocationTextView.setText(title);
                mLocationTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity B**

```
public class StateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == AlertCreationActivity.ALERT_CREATION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(AlertCreationActivity.ALERT_CREATION_REQUEST_DATA, data.getStringExtra(AlertCreationActivity.ALERT_CREATION_REQUEST_DATA));
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity B's adapter is where the next intent happens**

```
public class StateAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StateAdapter.StateViewHolder>  {

    // Other Adapter methods not shown

    public class StateViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        // Other View Holder methods not shown

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            State selectedState = getStateBy(mLocationLabel.getText().toString());

            // Save state ID
            LocationStorage storage = new LocationStorage(mActivity);
            storage.setSelectedStateId(selectedState.getId());
            storage.setSelectedStateName(selectedState.getName());

            Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, SpotActivity.class);
            mActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, AlertCreationActivity.ALERT_CREATION_REQUEST_CODE);               

        }
    }
}
```

**Activity C**

```
public class SpotActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         // Initialize actionbar and recyclerview adapter

         // a click on a recyclerview's list item triggers this method
         adapter.setSurfSpotSelectedListener(new SurfSpotSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSpotSelected(String spotName) {               
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra(AlertCreationActivity.ALERT_CREATION_REQUEST_DATA, spotName);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does navigate back to `activity` C mean?If you dont start C By `startActivityForResult`,you will get no result in B.

Comment: Well activity B is a recyclerview of states. When a state is clicked activity C is launched which displays a recylcerview of spots for that state. When the user is reviewing spots for a particular state and decides that is not the correct state, hits the back button on the toolbar and then (In activity B) chooses the same state or another which launches activity C again. Activity B does start activity C by startActivityForResult

Comment: Also it is worth noting that In the above situation. When the user selects a spot Activity B onActivityResult intent does contain the data from Activity C. However when the data hits activity A it is now null

Comment: launchMode is all standard?

Comment: Yup. The only activity that does not have the default launch mode is my search activity. Which is only activated when the search icon is clicked on the toolbar.

Comment: in your code ,It seems like when you click back arrow ,you go to B, the  B directly back to A.

Comment: if (requestCode == AlertCreationActivity.ALERT_CREATION_REQUEST_CODE)  u haven't check RESULT_OK in B

Comment: I added the check for RESULT_OK in activity B and nothing changed the code inside the if statement is still being executed with the correct data. Also When I click the back arrow from activity C, I go to activity B. Then I can either click the back arrow which would actually bring me back to an activity before activity A (going to fix this) or go click a state and go to activity C again

Comment: Then I can either click the back arrow which would actually bring me back to an activity before activity A (going to fix this).you mean when you click back on B,you dont back to A?

Comment: It does now. Activity A is the parent of Activity B which is the parent of Activity C.

Comment: What' your problem now?

Comment: That Activity a does not receive the result intent (its null) when the following sequence happens. A->B->C->B->C

Comment: what about setClass for new Intent in activity B' on ActivtyResut?

Comment: Didn't work. I should note that after testing the same sequence using the android back button it does successfully work. I wonder what the android back button does that the toolbar back button does not do.

Comment: What does toolbar back button do ?

Comment: I have not programmed it to do anything specific. It just goes back to the previous activity. I am going to try Good Try's solution and have Activity B's back button finish the activity. without passing an intent back. Maybe thats what the normal flow of the android back button is

Comment: I'd like to custom toolbar back button to just finish Activiy.I think the toolbar

Comment: I ended up solving it by setting the setNavigationOnClickListener for the toolbar in Activity C. Thanks for all your help I apperciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You should set your result by overriding OnBackPressed(), for example:

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(111, new Intent().putExtra("result", "from c"));
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

For Actionbar, you should overriding onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        //here
        setResult(111, new Intent().putExtra("result", "from c"));
        this.finish();
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: onBackPressed() does not execute when hitting the toolbar's back arrow. I believe it is only for the android back button on the device.

Comment: it seems like that  it will  still  trigger onActivityResult if you dont setRsult.

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake , but may be your crash log is Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference?

Comment: In activity A if I do not check that the resultCode == RESULT_OK I do receive a null pointer exception because the data parameter is null.

Comment: I've edit my answer and hope it will be more helpful.

Comment: Where would you place this code? Would it be in Activity C?

Comment: I ended up solving it by setting the setNavigationOnClickListener for the toolbar in Activity C. Thanks for all your help I apperciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it by setting the setNavigationOnClickListener for the toolbar in Acitvity B andActivity C  and calling onBackPressed() to mimic back navigation. Thanks for all your help Tiny Sunlight and Good Try. Here is my Activity B & C. I hope this helps others.

**Activity B**

```
public class StateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Bind(R.id.toolBar) Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spot_selection);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        // Recyclerview and Adapter left out for brevity

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == AlertCreationActivity.ALERT_CREATION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(AlertCreationActivity.ALERT_CREATION_REQUEST_DATA, data.getStringExtra(AlertCreationActivity.ALERT_CREATION_REQUEST_DATA));
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity C**

```
public class SpotActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Bind(R.id.toolBar) Toolbar mToolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spot_selection);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });     

    // Setting up Recyclerview and Adapter omitted

        adapter.setSurfSpotSelectedListener(new SurfSpotSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSpotSelected(String spotName) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra(AlertCreationActivity.ALERT_CREATION_REQUEST_DATA, spotName);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```